# Index with business days in xts

Tags: r, xts

there is a very handy feature in `pandas`, which allows you to create an index with weekdays `freq=BDay()`, so you can fill missing data with NAs. Does anyone aware of a such functionality in `xts`? I know that you can do something like

```
new_index <- sql(date1, date2, by = "1 day")
new_index <- new_index[!weekday(new_index) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")] 
my_xts <- xts(data, index = new_index)
```

But maybe there is a build-in `xts` functionality to do that.

Comment: Have a look at `timeDate` 's function `isBizday`. it should do what you are asking for.

Comment: This function uses uses isWeekday which uses wday form as.POSIX. It is all fine, just wonder is there any functionality in xts.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at, `?.index`. Here you'll find the following extraction methods:

```
.indexday(x)
.indexmday(x)
.indexwday(x)
.indexweek(x)
.indexmon(x)
.indexyday(x)
.indexyear(x)
.indexhour(x)
.indexmin(x)
.indexsec(x)
```

ie. in your case we could use `.indexwday(x)` (which returns an integer `0:6`) and try something like

```
library(xts)
my_xts <- xts(rnorm(100), seq(as.Date("2016-10-01"), length.out = 100, by = 1))
new_index <- index(my_xts)
my_xts[! .indexwday(my_xts) %in% 1:5] <- NA
```

in order to fill the series with `NA` for sunday (0) and saturday (6).